# Cover nodes at distance X from given node

Tags: algorithms

Given a tree with $N$ nodes and $N-1$ edges where each edge has weight equal to $1$.
Now we are given a query which provides $Y$ pairs of type $(A,B)$ It means cover all those vertices that are at most at a distance of $B$($B$ inclusive)  from $A$ node.We need to count all the vertices that can be covered with these $Y$ pairs.

**EXAMPLE :**

Let tree be this :

[image]

And let we have $2$ pairs as follow : $(I,3)$ and $(L,5)$ then here answer will be $16$ as all nodes can be covered expect  {$K,G,Q,J$}

So how to approach this question in best efficient manner as count of these Queries can be very high and each query $ith$ Query will be having $K[i]$ such pairs.

Queries can be maximum $50000$ and number of nodes that is $N$ can also be at max $50000$.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @Bilou06 One approach can be to run a DFS till we can do it for particulr node and continue it for all nodes in each query .But obviously its going to be quite inefficient

Answer (score 0):

Given a set L of $(A_i, k_i)$, you can do a large BFS:

```
sort L with k_i decreasing
r = set() # results
while L not empty:
    remove (A,i) first element from L
    add A to r
    if i>1:
        for B neighbourg of A:
            if B not in r:
                if B,x in L, replace x with max(x, i-i)
                else add (B, i-1) to L
    sort L with k_i decreasing
return lenght(r)
```

Of course, you may want to pay attention to the structure of L. I chose a list to make the algorithm readable, but it is not a good choice here. You may use a list of couple (k,set). A set being all the points at distance k. You may also use a dictonary, or both.